# SQL Server Import Export Wizard executing but not writing rows to file

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, ssms

I am trying to export data from a database using the export wizard. My destination is a delimited flat file with a custom text qualifier(^`~) because the data in one of the fields I am exporting may contain basically every character known to man. So I am able to set up the query in the wizard just fine, and it executes with 0 errors, everything's good. But it shows that it has written no records to the destination file. Now, I know my query returns records, but it is somewhat of a multistep query. It goes something like this:

DECLARE @RecordCount AS INT
SET @RecordCount = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SomeTable WHERE COLUMN1 = 1 AND COLUMN2 = 2

DECLARE @TempTable AS TABLE(
    COLUMN1 INT,
    COLUMN2 INT,
    COLUMN3 VARCHAR(255))
INSERT INTO @TempTable
    SELECT Column1,
           Column2,
           Column3,
           Column4
    FROM SomeOtherTable
    WHERE Column1 IN (--Sub Query that gets a random list of ids)

SELECT TOP(@RecordCount)
    A.COLUMN1,
    A.COLUMN2,
    A.COLUMN3,
    A.COLUMN4,
    B.COLUMN1,
    B.COLUMN2,
    B.COLUMN3
FROM @TempTable A
INNER JOIN JoinTable B ON A.COLUMN1 = B.COLUMN1
ORDER BY COLUMN1

Like I said, the query works just fine when run in Ssms, it's only when using the export wizard that I have the issue of it not actually writing any rows to the destination. I would simply save the query results as a csv, but the comma delimiter is not possible for me because of the data in the fields, which is why I need the export wizard to declare a custom text qualifier. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a view with your query and exporting it that way. You may have some problems with the temp variables you're creating.

When you click preview in the wizard, is it populating?

Comment: I will try the view, although I believe I do not have write permissions to the database. My company is a financial institution, so getting permissions to do anything is a battle in and of itself. The query takes an exceptionally long time to run, as there are about 800 million records in one of the join tables, so I haven't checked the preview. I will try that today and see, although even if it does show up there, I still have the issue of it not writing the records to the file.

Comment: I wonder then if It could be timing out since the query takes so long. I'll continue to look into it.

Comment: I thought the same thing at first, but I would expect to get a timeout error or something, rather than query completed successfully, 0 rows transferred.